# Scala StackOverflow error while creating the object of the class inside class

Tags: scala

I defined my scala class as follows:

```
scala> class test2(private var a:Int) {
     | var  t1 = new test2(10)
     | println(t1.a)
     | }
defined class test2
```

Now when i try to create the object of this class i am getting stackoverflow error (see below).

```
scala> var t2 = new test2(5)
java.lang.StackOverflowError
  ... 1024 elided
```

Can anyone explain why is this error coming ?

It is not a duplicate. The problem posted in the link is related to java. My problem is related to scala.

Comment: How many `test2` objects do you expect to be created here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StackOverFlowError when initializing constructor for a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20320102/stackoverflowerror-when-initializing-constructor-for-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new object inside constructor which is recursively creating new object and it continues. So stack overflow error occurred

Comment: Could you please explain how is it creating a new object inside a constructor ?  I have not defined any auxilary constructor here.

Comment: In Scala everything you write in a class can be thought of being inside a constructor. While you create new test2(5), it creates new test2(10) that in turn creates new test2(10) and it goes on until it throws an exception. Why would you create object inside the same class's constructor?

Comment: Is it always the case that whatever i write in the scala class body will be by default considered as the constructor body ? Yeah it does not make any sense to  create new object inside constructor..

Comment: Yes. this method can be defined to create auxiliary constructors. Anything except this methods is a part of primary constructor

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help and explaination.